# String.split() in Karate Feature File returning exceptions

Tags: javascript, dsl, karate

I'm unsure about how I can split the response string from an already created feature to obtain the response header "Location" value.

**What I've tried**

1)

```
Feature: Create Tariff

  Background:
  * def result = call read('../../get-user-token.feature')
  * def serviceId = call read('create-service.feature')

  Scenario: Create Tariff
    Given url 'https://app-dev.topbox.pro/tariff-svc/api/v1/tariffs'
    And header Authorization = result.response.token_type + " " + result.response.access_token
    And request
      """
      {
      serviceTypeId: '#(serviceId.responseHeaders['Location'].split('/')[1])',
      owner: 1,
      type: 0,
      pencePerMile: '69.69',
      minMileage: '1.00',
      minCost: 5,
      zoneFrom: '',
      zoneTo: '',
      fixedCost: 0
      }
      """
    When method POST
    Then status 201
```

Which resulted in...

> IntegrationTests.TestSetup.create-tariff: create-tariff.feature:10 -
>   net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected token L at position
>   46.

2)

```
Feature: Create Tariff

  Background:
  * def result = call read('../../get-user-token.feature')
  * def serviceId = call read('create-service.feature').responseHeaders['Location'].split('/')[1]

  Scenario: Create Tariff
    Given url 'https://app-dev.topbox.pro/tariff-svc/api/v1/tariffs'
    And header Authorization = result.response.token_type + " " + result.response.access_token
    And request
      """
      {
      serviceTypeId: '#(serviceId)',
      owner: 1,
      type: 0,
      pencePerMile: '69.69',
      minMileage: '1.00',
      minCost: 5,
      zoneFrom: '',
      zoneTo: '',
      fixedCost: 0
      }
      """
    When method POST
    Then status 201
```

Which resulted in...

> failed features: IntegrationTests.TestSetup.create-tariff: -unknown-:5
>   - javascript evaluation failed: read('create-service.feature').responseHeaders['Location'].split('/')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpNMr.png),
>   TypeError: Cannot read property "Location" from undefined in  at
>   line number 1

**NOTE**
The specified feature "create-service.feature" does indeed work when isolated and does produce the response header, as shown below

[image: Location Header Response]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `lastIndexOf` instead of `split`:

```
* def location = responseHeaders['Location'][0]
* def serviceId = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a Javascript function : https://github.com/intuit/karate#javascript-functions

```
* def greeter = function(name){ return 'hello ' + name }
* assert greeter('Bob') == 'hello Bob'
```

EDIT:

```
* def service = { key : "someinfo/myServiceId"}
* def func = function(service){return service.key.split('/')[1]}
* def serviceId = func(service)
* match serviceId == "myServiceId"
```

Comment: unfortunately, this didnt seem to work either "failed features:
IntegrationTests.TestSetup.create-tariff: -unknown-:7 - javascript evaluation failed: func(service), TypeError: service.responseHeaders.Location.split is not a function in <eval> at line number 1"

Comment: Then the problem has to be with service.responseHeaders['Location'], and not with the split. I edited my answer with a working call to split().

Answer (score 1):

I think the first error is due to single quotes inside your expression, try escaping that

like,

```
And request
"""
{
serviceTypeId: '#(serviceId.responseHeaders.Location[0].split(\'/\')[1])',
owner: 1,
type: 0,
pencePerMile: '69.69',
minMileage: '1.00',
minCost: 5,
zoneFrom: '',
zoneTo: '',
fixedCost: 0
}
"""
```

Edit: Just now noted each value in responseHeader has a list type value so access it like Location[0]

And your second Approach should be something like this,

```
* def serviceId = call read('create-service.feature').responseHeaders.Location[0].split('/')[1]
```

Comment: unfortunately the server side response took that as a literal string ' "detail":{"Property":"serviceTypeId","Message":"Invalid guid format","Value":"#(serviceId.responseHeaders.Location[0].split('/')[1])"}} ' rather than the actual value of the Location Response Header

Answer (score 0):

I just face the same issue (*.split is not a function*), and in my case, I need to convert the data to string first, before using split function.

Here is the custom code from [adrien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10791639/adrien) answer:

```
* def service = { key : "someinfo/myServiceId"}
* def func = function(service){return service.key.toString().split('/')[1]}
```