# How can I use location from Response Headers in the next request?

Tags: karate

I'm perfoming some test using Karate test.

1st a Post that is expecting a 201 and a location.

2nd use the location from response to perfom a get.

Does anyone know how can I do this with Karate?

The following code is my try, after many other.

```
Given path 'alpha/test'
And request
"""
 {
   "id": '#(uuid)',
    "content": "test",
    "isActive": true
 }
"""
When method post
Then status 201
And def endpointLocation = responseHeaders['Location']
And print endpointLocation

Given url 'endpointLocation'
When method get
Then status 200
And match response ==
"""
 {
   "id": '#(uuid)'
 }
"""
```

But i'm getting:

```
18:30:12.819 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException, http call failed after 252 milliseconds for URL: endpointLocation
18:30:12.820 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: 
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
testApi.feature:263 -
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
```

I'm not figuring it out why.

[EDIT]

After sugestion from Peter, that I Thanks!

The print return:

08:59:33.610 [main] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] [
  "https://www.test.com/enpoint/4603b043-ea8c-470d-a5a9-2aa50aea4f75"]

Now I'm calling

Given url endpointLocation

and I'm getting

08:59:33.611 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: ["https://www.test.com/enpoint/4603b043-ea8c-470d-a5a9-2aa50aea4f75"]
fraudMgmtApi.feature:263 - java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: ["https://www.test.com/enpoint/4603b043-ea8c-470d-a5a9-2aa50aea4f75"]

I was trying also to trim the first and last caracters, creating a:

- def trim =
  """
  function(myText) { result = myText.substring(1, myText.length-1) }
  """

Or myText.slice(1,-1)

Answer (score 0):

From the error message: `http call failed after 252 milliseconds for URL: endpointLocation`

It is clear you are setting the `url` wrong. First try hard-coding it, then make this change, if the `endpointLocation` variable is set correctly. You can `print` it to check.

```
Given url endpointLocation
```

Comment: Thanks @peter-thomas , I have Update my question. (didn't know how to update bellow your answer :\

Comment: @DavidGonçalves refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46361842/143475 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54556300/143475